# Kiwi stub isn't working with NSNumber, ends in SIGKILL

Tags: ios, objective-c, tdd, kiwi

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right but I'm trying to stub an NSNumber property on a core data object.

Here's my test example:

```
   it(@"should say 1 / ? with 1 point", ^{
            mockCard = [KWMock nullMockForClass:[Card class]];
            [mockCard stub:@selector(points) andReturn:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
            controller.card = mockCard;
            [[controller.lblCount.text should] equal:@"1 / ?"];     
   });
```

And my source code:

```
 -(void)setCard:(Card *)aCard{
     if ([card.points intValue] == 1) {
          lblCount.text = @"1 / ?";
     }
 }
```

Running this causes a `SIGKIL` error in the `writeObjectValueToInvocationReturnValue` method.

Am I missing something?

### Update

attempted to change the stub to:

```
[mockCard stub:@selector(points) andReturn:theValue(1)]
...

 [FAILED], wrapped stub value type (i) could not be converted to the target type (v)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is bug in Kiwi and is described here: https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/issues/63

Comment: 404, this is why you shouldn't just post links.

Comment: The github repo has been moved: The issue is now at: https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/issues/63